# Confused concept of " force" in ordinary language versus precise concepts in physics

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

I'd like to be able ( for philosophical purposes) to illustrate this general idea : " science makes clear and precise concepts that are confused in ordinary/prescientific  thought".

I think that a good example could be the concept of force.

I'd like to know in how many ways, in physics, the following sentence could be completed:

```
     force should not be confused with   ____________
```

In other words, I'd like to know what are the different cases in which a physicist could say that the word " force" is not used correctly in ordinary language.

Also, are there *common physics fallacies that can be refuted* using precise distinctions relative to force and other physical quantities?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To get you started... momentum, velocity, acceleration, energy, impulse, effort, intention.

Comment: For example, a common misconception is that the normal force isn't a force, because there's no _effort_ involved. Students will say "the table doesn't keep the book up with a normal force, it just gets in its way".

Comment: It is more consistent with reality to say that science often seizes words from ordinary or pre-scientific language, and then provides a new definition of them which is then inconsistent with the ordinary meaning. Words are always used correctly in ordinary language, if they are used in ways consistent with their ordinary meaning - which I think is the opposite to what you propose, that a physicist should be able to seize a word from ordinary language, provide it with new meaning, and then deny the correctness of using the word according to its ordinary meaning.

Comment: @Steve. I was thinking of cases where the ordinary meaning of words prevents from understanding correctly a physical concept, or is the origin of a fallacy. I do not want to suggest that scientific definitions should be substituted for  the ordinary meaning of words in ordinary contexts.

Comment: @Steve. I'm also looking for examples of the fact that making precise conceptual distinctions can be really enlightning, intellectually speaking.

Comment: @RayLittleRock, the standard way of avoiding fallacies or misunderstandings is to diversify the vocabulary, and use different words for different things (particularly where confusion or conflation has frequently been found in practice). Law is an example of a profession where archaic words are often held over because they have precise contextual meanings, or where words with special meanings are systematically capitalised. Most of science also borrows heavily from Greek and Latin. In my experience, physics is unrivalled as a profession that makes extensive use of linguistic "false friends"!

Comment: As for 'the enlightenment that comes from making subtle conceptual distinctions', what sort of example are you looking for? I mean almost any instance of learning involves acquiring new concepts and making a new distinction (that the person didn't previously make).

Comment: @knzhou, the obvious question then to ask, is why doesn't the book fall to the floor? The table must be exerting force against the book in order to resist gravity. Would the same student, if they sat on a large spring, argue that they could feel no force, and that it was merely getting in the way of their falling to the floor? The table is simply less elastic than the spring. I suspect these are not mere language confusion problems - they are problems to do with the students prior philosophy and the way in which they have thus far made sense of the world.

Comment: @Steve There's plenty of research on this. You get a wide range of responses. A lot of people simply cannot notice there is a contradiction with $F=ma$, and when this is pointed out, may just say it's an exception to $F=ma$. I imagine many would say that the spring is different because it's "actively pushing back", unlike the table which is "just sitting there". Look up the Force Concept Inventory and the average results!

Comment: @Steve My impression is that the consensus in physics education research is that if we want to rid most students of misconceptions like this, we must devote an entire semester to these ideas alone. That is, mechanics courses are basically stripped down to kinematics, Newton's laws, linear momentum, kinetic energy, and gravitational/elastic potential energy, all in one dimension only.

Comment: What about "this is just a theory"?

Comment: @knzhou, that may well be the case. There isn't any substitute for actually teaching the conceptual knowledge - that is, the philosophy of it.

Comment: @Steve Actually, research shows that just teaching "the philosophy of it" yields among the worst results; it just doesn't sink in. You can tell people "note how this is different from your intuition", or "note how this is different from how it's popularly described" all day, but it doesn't stick at all, unless you have them do practice problems and lab demonstrations. You have to give them the time to personally apply their pre-Newtonian thinking, then _immediately_ show that this gives the wrong answer.

Comment: @knzhou, and regards the spring, another analogy might be a seesaw - it is apparent that if a person stands on one side and lifts a small child on the other, force is being applied upwards to the child. You can then reduce this to a cantilever (like a gang plank on a ship) that does not move but can uphold a mass at its end, and finally reduce the length of the plank until the situation is equivalent to standing on the table-top supported purely from below rather than across - and then ask, if the seesaw is able to exert upwards force, then why is there any difference with the table?

Comment: @knzhou, agreed. I'm not proposing any particular way in which the philosophy is taught - or that it can be taught only by lecture - only that it must be taught. If that requires practical experiment to be convincing, then so be it!

Comment: @Steve Well that's an easy one. The seesaw has another person on it, while the table's just a table. That's why a table can't exert force. :P Now, I agree with what you're saying, but I just doubt that any good analogies or arguments will change the averages. Thousands of physicists have been cranking these out for a very long time and the post-class exam averages remain abysmal.

Comment: @knzhou, indeed! As I say, there is no substitute for teaching physical philosophy, including whatever steps are necessary to make it convincing. All people first acquire a physical philosophy as children through pure inference from a limited range of practical experience - usually, the word "force" is understood as situations where there is an urge to move, not normally as also encompassing resistance to movement...

Comment: ...Even in formulations like "the policeman forced me to stop", the force is vaguely assumed to be the compulsion for the person to bring themselves to a stop, or the policeman's bringing of objects into the person's path, applying force indirectly to create a physical arrangement that will passively resist the person's further movement, rather than impose opposite forces directly. That is, force is active in nature, and excludes the pure inertia of stationary objects or deadweight resistance and similar things. Physics actually generalises the word force rather than making it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best example I can think of is from the original Star Wars movie, in which Darth Vader intones: "Never underestimate the power of THE FORCE".  What he should have said (to make the units come out right) was:

"Never underestimate the power of THE FORCE times distance divided by time".